# How do I move the Outlook 2011 files from Documents on Mac OS X?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2011, office-for-mac

I have installed Office 2011 Business on my new MacBook Pro and it created three directories in my documents that really don't belong there:

- Microsoft User Data
- Outlook Temp
- RDC Connection

I would like to move these file out of there. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the Microsoft User Data folder to ~/Library/Preferences and it will work just fine.  Not sure about the other two.